# filesize is not growing as expected

Tags: linux, audio, command-line, ffmpeg, file-management

I am trying to record a stream here on my machine to study ffmpeg library,
but with(out) success.

I have a file watcher to clean up bugged streams, that cleanup each 3 minutes files that have been not changed less then 3 minutes.

The real problem is, if I use the command below:

`/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i http://sysrad.net:10090/ -y test.mp3`

this command doesn't have any kind of codec or audio transformation, so my target file (test.mp3) become 256k quickly, but, if I use this command below:

`/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i http://sysrad.net:10090/ -y -b:a 8k -ac 1 -ar 11025 test.mp3`

My target file (test.mp3) keep 0k until the record has 256k, I am not sure if this is an Unix problem or ffmpeg problem.

Other information, if I run in loop:

`while true; do wc -l teste.mp3; sleep 0.5; done;`

test.mp3 file keeps 0 rows, until has 256k size...

I have no idea how to workaround that, to get the real time file size for each 1k that ffmpeg get from stream with those codecs, does you guys have any idea how can I handle that?

Thanks!!!!